# Is javascript event target always needed?

Tags: javascript, events

Im new in JS, and i was wondering do events always need target element? 
Because if you doing some logic programming you dont need to include DOM elements, and i have also noticed that in some libraries ie. Jquery, you can fire events on regular JS objects.

Comment: The event target would be the regular JS Object then. It doesn't have to be a DOM element object.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: What i meant was do events always need to be associated  with something? Does exist anything like "general events" Lets say i have app called "time" and in that  function "celebration" which i want to call on event newyear. Do i have to bind newyear to dom element or Js object?

Answer (score 0):

Here i made a example for you with some code with events and element added after page load: sorry for bad languaje.
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DWjYH/)